# When do the Facebook graph api endpoints return an array wrapped in a { data: ... } object?

Tags: arrays, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Some Facebook graph api endpoints return arrays like this:

```
"likes": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "000000", 
        "name": "Somebody"
      }
    ], 
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "after": ".....", 
        "before": "....."
      }
    }
}
```

While others return arrays like this:

```
"actions": [
    {
      "name": "Comment", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/000000/posts/00000"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Like", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/00000/posts/00000"
    }
  ]
```

Does anyone know of where in the documentation Facebook explains when an array is going to be returned wrapped in a `{ data: [...] }` object? As far as I know, facebook just lists everything that is an array as `array` and doesn't explain when a data object will be returned.

I guess I can assume that if something can be "paged" that it will be in a data structure...

Am I missing some documentation about Facebook data types somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, they seem to list everything that is an `array` as `array`.

For instance, [in the documentation for the Post Endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/), the return type for both "likes" and "actions" is listed as an array.

```
Likes   
...
Array of objects containing the id and name fields. 
Requesting with summary=1 will also return a summary object 
containing the total_count of likes.

Actions
...
Array of objects containing the name and link
```

I think that's why you have to query the actual end point, and inspect the JSON (like you are doing) and figure out what is actually coming back.

No wonder the Facebook API is the [proud winner of the "**Worst API**" Award](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/facebook/developer-survey-finds-facebook-has-the-worst-api/2533)!

Answer (score 0):

Any feed(feeds/posts)(that is every array) you retrieve will be retured in `data` object, inside this `data` object the array will be there.Also the friend list is embedded in `data` object,which will have array of objects. Something like this:

```
{"data": [
      {
        "id": "..", 
        "name": ".."
      }
    ], 
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "after": ".....", 
        "before": "....."
      }
    }
}
```

While in all other api requests , which do not return an array, have structure like this:

```
   {
        "id": "..", 
        "name": ".."
      }
```